# "Exclusive" inheritance: requirement for certain forms of multiple inheritance

Tags: java, c++, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Is there a way in C++ or Java (or any other popular language) to make restrictions on what classes can extend/inherit a given class? Specifically, is it possible to enforce a particular pattern for multiple inheritance when a certain class is be being extended?

I titled this post "exclusive inheritance" because this would constitute a form of inheritance where certain classes would have an exclusive "privilege" to extend a potential superclass.

Let's say we have already defined the following classes (I will use the `extends` keyword for simplicity, not to be language bound):

```
Visualizable
Timeable
Maskable
ExperimentalData

Trial extends ExperimentalData
TimeStampedData extends Timeable
PositionData extends Visualizable
```

Two scenarios:

1. We would like to define a new class `ShortPass` that inherits from the class `Maskable`, but we want the following to be an invalid way to extend `Maskable`:

   ```
   ShortPass extends PositionData, Maskable
   ```

   Rather the following should be used

   ```
   ShortPass extends PositionData, Timeable, Maskable
   ```
2. We want any class that is `Timeable` OR `Visualizable` to be able to extend `Maskable` and nothing else so that the following are valid:

   ```
   ShortPass extends PositionData, Maskable
   ```

   or

   ```
   ShortPass extends TimeStampedData, Maskable
   ```

   But never

   ```
   Trial extends Maskable
   ShortPass extends Visualizable, Timeable, Maskable
   ```

I know one way to get around scenario 1 is to define `Maskable` by inheriting from `Timeable` and `Visualizable`, but what if scenario 2 is the case (e.g. program specification requires that a class, say `ShortPass`, be either `Visualizable` OR `Timeable` not both (say, because there's no point in defining `ShortPass` as both `Visualizable` and `Timeable`))?

Comment: Why do you want to do this

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

My first thought on this would be declaring the class as `final` so it cannot serve as a super class at all. I assume you already know this, so moving onto my second thought,

This would only be for `interfaces`, however an interface implementing another interface would work (if you want an interface A to be implemented with another interface B only). However this introduces the possibility of implementing the interface B independently. (though you already noted this, just stating that this is indeed a good way)